# Objects disappeared and only show up in final render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, blender-internal-render-engine, 3d-view

I added a tiny object, while i finished editing, all the other objects dissapeared from all the viewing modes, they only show up on the final rendered image. I'm making a guitar by the way.

This is the tiny object i added on solid mode, it also shows up the same on rendered mode:

[image]

Heres the rendered image showing the other objects beside it:

[image]

That's not the first time this happens, i always have to start another project from scratch.

It might be wrong but i think this always happens after i save the file while editing it.

How do i proceed ???

Comment: You are in local view which shows only one object. You can turn it on/off with "numpad/".

Comment: @Yan Amorim [up your blend please](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) I can't replicate your bug, so it will be easier to see it in your blend file

Comment: Solved! Thanks.

Comment: great, what was the solution?

Answer (score 1):

GUYS IT WAS LOCAL VIEW YOU CAN CHANGE IT TO GLOBAL VIEW ON THE "VIEW" OPTIONS OR TYPE "**/**" ON THE NUMPAD.

I was confused because i'm not a native speaker and people told me to type numpad/ which i  understood to be deactivate/activate the numpad.

Comment: Wow, that's nuts. Blender should throw up a message someplace the first time you use that in a file in case you don't notice